# Find files with Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, os.walk

I'm trying to find files in a directory.

The files I'd like to find can be named in two possible ways.
It's either a combination of three capital letters and the file extension (e.g.: "ABC.xlsx") or a combination of 3 capital letters, the string "_diff" and the extension (e.g.: "ABC_diff.xlsx").

This is my code until now:

```
def find_files(directory): # Function that iterates over files in a directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for basename in files:
        if re.match(r'\b[A-Z]+\b.xlsx', basename):
            basename = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]
            yield basename
```

This function is able to find the "ABC.xlsx" kind of files, but I would like to be able to find both possibilities.

Comment: Check [this site - regex101](https://regex101.com/) which has a "Quick reference" as well as allowing you to experiment.

Comment: What was wrong with using `else if` and a second pattern for the "_diff" files?

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.search()` function with the following pattern:

```
...
if re.search(r'[A-Z]{3}(_diff)?\.xlsx$', basename):
```